# unit test repetition issue

Tags: c#, unit-testing, repeat

Tests are here and they are extremely repetitive, which I would like to change…

```
     [TestClass]
    public class CompareDataTest
    {
private void GenerateTerms(int firstTerm, int secondTerm, out TaughtUnit firstGrade, out TaughtUnit secondGrade)
        {
            firstGrade = new TaughtUnit("foo");
            secondGrade = new TaughtUnit("bar");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void CompareResultsTest1()
        {
            var firstGrade = new TaughtUnit("foo");
            firstGrade.Percentage.Add("GRADE", 38);
            var secondGrade = new TaughtUnit("foo");
            secondGrade.Percentage.Add("GRADE", 70);
            var oldTerm = new List<TaughtUnit>() { firstGrade };
            var newTerm = new List<TaughtUnit>() { secondGrade };
            var rankBefore = firstGrade.Percentage;
            var rankNow = secondGrade.Percentage;
            var messages = Program.CompareData(oldTerm, newTerm);

            Assert.AreEqual(0, messages.Count);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void CompareResultsTest2()
        {
            var firstGrade = new TaughtUnit("foo");
            firstGrade.Percentage.Add("GRADE", 0);
            var secondGrade = new TaughtUnit("foo");
            secondGrade.Percentage.Add("GRADE", 35);
            var oldTerm = new List<TaughtUnit>() { firstGrade };
            var newTerm = new List<TaughtUnit>() { secondGrade };
            var rankBefore = firstGrade.Percentage;
            var rankNow = secondGrade.Percentage;
            int gradeOld = 0; int gradeNew = 10;
            var getGradeOld = firstGrade.Percentage.TryGetValue("GRADE", out gradeOld);
            var getGradeNew = secondGrade.Percentage.TryGetValue("GRADE", out gradeNew);
            var difference = gradeNew - gradeOld;

            var messages = Program.CompareData(oldTerm, newTerm);

            Assert.AreEqual(1, messages.Count);
            Assert.AreEqual("foo: GRADE rank has dropped by 30", messages[0]);
        }
```

I think I should use a private void before the set of tests, but I do not know how…
How do I refer to what is created in private void?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare those variable at Test class level. Populate the setup variable using private method.

```
 [TestClass]
public class CompareDataTest
{
    private TaughtUnit firstGrade;
    private TaughtUnit secondGrade;

    private void GenerateTerms(int firstTerm, int secondTerm, out TaughtUnit firstGrade, out TaughtUnit secondGrade)
    {
        firstGrade = new TaughtUnit("foo");
        secondGrade = new TaughtUnit("bar");
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void CompareResultsTest1()
    {
        GenerateTerms(..., ..., ..)
        firstGrade.Percentage.Add("GRADE", 38);
        secondGrade.Percentage.Add("GRADE", 70);

        // rest of other things you want to set specific to the test.

        Assert.AreEqual(0, messages.Count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NUnit Framework has a number of ways to passin a Value Source for your tests.

For example I could test Guid.Parse like so

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> Datas
    {
        get
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(0, 100) //Lots of numbers
                             .ToDictionary(x => x, x => Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void MultiCacheTest([ValueSource("Datas")] KeyValuePair<int, string> item)
    {                       
        //ACT ...Yes this tests Guid.Parse 100 times
        var value = Guid.Parse(item.value);

        Assert.AreEqual(item.Value, value.ToString());           
    }
```

The idea would be to pass all the purmutations needed to test all the various paths your **unit** could take and allow the key of the pair to be the input value of the method, with the value of the pair being the expected result. In your case you might pass in 2 percentage values as the key *"0|35"* and *"foo: GRADE rank has dropped by 30"* would be the expected value.